# Selenium-Webdriver in Ruby with minitest. How to define parallelize_me amount

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, minitest

I'm testing Minitest to compare it to Rspec, and I'm right now testing the parallelize_me! option. The thing is that it runs only 2 jobs simultaneously, and, with a 4 core CPU I think it can run up to 4 jobs simultaneously, but maybe Im wrong.

Is there a parameter or setting to define the ammount of jobs that runs simultaneously?

I'm talking about the `parallelize_me!` option in the tests.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/hell'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class Web_Test < MiniTest::Test
    parallelize_me!
    def setup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:
http://chriskottom.com/blog/2014/10/exploring-minitest-concurrency/

```
$ N=4 rake test
```

or

```
$ N=4 ruby path/to/test/suite.rb
```

> One additional feature that’s not documented anywhere that I could
>   find except in the source code: you can specify the number of worker
>   threads started and run by Minitest::Parallel::Executor by providing
>   an environment variable on the command line when you run your tests
>   like so: N=4 rake test. (Minitest defaults to N=2 if no other value is
>   given.)